# Zend Framework-does every webpage have it's own controller and indexAction and view?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm wanting to be sure that I am setting things up correctly.  On a typical website with 10 pages, would each page have it's own controller with it's own IndexAction and it's own View folder with it's own index.phtml as a view?

Or do you have one controller with multiple Page1Action, Page2Action, etc  and have multiple differently named view.phtml pages within view/index folder?

I'm leaning toward the former because then I can have a cleaner controller for each page...

Is there a standard, or is it subjective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sitemap would play a major role in this question. But, in lieu of that, here's a few examples.

**Example 1. Flat**

```
/foo
/bar
/baz
```

You'll probably want to use separate controllers: Foo/IndexController.php, Bar/IndexController.php, and Baz/IndexController.php with each having an indexAction() method to pass information to your view (once again separate).

**Example 2. A Little Bit Lower Now**

```
/foo/bar
/baz
```

You'll only need two controllers: Foo/BarController and Baz/IndexController. If /foo needs a landing page you'll have to throw in a Foo/IndexController.php to be safe. Your actions are still indexAction(). Because you've not gone deep enough to hit that third level, your views are still index.phtml.

**Example 3. Straight Line**

```
/foo/bar/baz
```

You're down to onc controller: Foo/BarController.php. If you need landing pages for /foo and /foo/bar you'll need another controller for /foo (Foo/IndexController) and an indexAction() for both. With /foo/bar/baz you're actually down to a slightly different action now too - bazAction() (inside Foo/BarController.php). Your view is now baz.phtml.

**Summary.**

The wider the sitemap the more controllers you have and fewer actions. The more narrow the sitemap the fewer the controllers and more actions.

**Postscript.**

I should also state, this is also contingent on using default routing patterns. If you do something a little more sophisticated in routing patterns, this is all shot out the window. Sometimes we use routes to keep the number of classes manageable. When we have a wide sitemap it's possible to create some custom routes and use __call() within a controller to hand-off view data appropriately. Just another way to skin this cat.

Comment: This is a great answer! You really cleared up a lot of confusion for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would create one Controller for a related group of Actions.  What related means is subjective.

*Very roughly speaking,* a group of related Actions operates on the same Model.  At least that's a good starting point, but it rarely works out that simply, because few real-world applications consist solely of CRUD operations on each Model.

If you decouple the Model from being simply a data access component, you can more sensibly define a logical grouping of Controller Actions for a Model.  A Model is where the majority of your code exists for business logic.  Database persistence is just an (optional) internal detail of the Model, to preserve *state* from request to request.  But a Model doesn't necessarily use a database.  It could be standalone, or it could be an aggregation of other Model objects.

By default, each Action has its own View script.  But this is also just a starting point, because you could use Layouts to make many View scripts share some if their markup in common, and you could use View Helpers and Partials and so on.